# upload file video on youtube using a python programm

Tags: python-3.x, video, youtube-data-api

I m working on a little project and I need a way to upload video on youtube using python programm, I searched on github and I find a programm that do this but it is in python2 and I need one in python3 also it is very difficult to manipulate. So does someone knows some programms thats **upload video on youtube** and it is written in **python3**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention the program that you had found, so I searched github.

The first hit is https://github.com/tokland/youtube-upload, and according to the readme, this is compatible with Python 3.x. You will need the google api python client too, and of course you will need an api key to use with it, but these are available.

An alternative is shoogle https://github.com/tokland/shoogle, which only supports python 3.x